# How to upload our dataset using pytorch when it is not present in torchvision?

Tags: programming, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, quantum-neural-network

I am trying to upload my dataset(SWELL-KW) instead of MNIST in  "Hybrid quantum-classical Neural Networks with PyTorch and Qiskit" provided by IBM qiskit but it says `"AttributeError: module 'torchvision.datasets' has no attribute 'SWELL'`. I could not find the dataset in torch vision. Is that the reason? If I try to give the path of dataset which is on my system, it indicates unicode error. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since the dataset does not exist in torchvision, trying to load it through torchvision will produce this error. Instead, save your SWELL-KW dataset as a .csv file, read it in, and convert the train/test data vectors, and labels each as their own PyTorch tensor.

For example, let's say I have my own custom dataset that consists of coordinate pairs and associated labels. I save the data into a file `myData.csv` such that the first column contains the x-coordinates, the second column contains the y-coordinates and the third column contains the labels. First, we load data row by row,

```
import csv
import torch
```

```
Xs = []
Ys = []

with open('myData.csv', mode ='r') as data:
    csvFile = csv.reader(data)
    for row in csvFile:
        Xs.append([float(row[0]), float(row[1])])
        Ys.append(float(row[2]))
```

and then we convert each of our lists to PyTorch tensors,

```
X_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(Xs)
Y_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(Ys)
```

Your data is now ready to use. For more complex datasets or specific use cases you may need to [create a custom dataset class](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).

Comment: Thank you. But since I am a beginner, please let me know how do I convert the dataset into pytorch tensor after reading the dataset using pd.read_csv()? I have a train and test data csv files on the system. I am trying to upload my dataset. what could be the steps?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq8PR.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkCFp.png

Comment: Sure, let me know if my latest edit helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I understood now.

Comment: Awesome! If your question resolved could you do me a favor and check-mark the answer? Thanks!